# Free cumulant generating function

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions, cumulants

The moments and cumulants of a real-valued random variable X is related via the cumulant-moment formula:
$$m_n = \sum_{\pi\in P(n)}\prod_{B\in\pi}c_{|B|},\qquad\qquad(1)$$
where $m_n(X)=E(X^n)$ is the moment and $c_n(X)$ is the cumulant, and the sum runs over partitions of $[n]:=\{1,2\dots,n\}$, i.e., $\pi = \{B_1,B_2,\dots\}$, such that $[n]$ is the disjoint union of the $B_i$'s.

The moments and cumulants are also related via a simple formula:
$$C(t) = \log M(t)=\log (E(\exp(tX))),\qquad\qquad(2)$$
where $$M(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{m_k}{k!}t^k\quad\text{and}\quad C(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_k}{k!}t^k$$ are the generating functions.

The moments $m$ and free cumulants $\kappa$ are related in a way similar to (1):
$$m_n = \sum_{\pi\in NC(n)}\prod_{B\in\pi}\kappa_{|B|},\qquad\qquad(3)$$
where the sum runs over the non-crossing partitions.

So my question is, is there a nice formula for the "free cumulant generating function" $K(t)$ similar to (2)?$$K(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\kappa_k}{k!}t^k.$$
Say, $$K(t)=\phi_2(E(\phi_1(tX)),$$ for some smooth functions $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, or even for $\phi_2=\phi_1^{-1}$?

Thanks in advance!

Some refs:

[J. Novak and P. ´Sniady, “What is...a free cumulant?"](http://www.ams.org/notices/201102/rtx110200300p.pdf)

J. A. Mingo and R. Speicher, Free Probability and Random Matrices, Springer, New York, 2017

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. One can define the generating functions without the factorials as $$M(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty m_n z^n,\quad C(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\kappa_n z^n.$$ Then your equation (3) is equivalent to ([Speicher 1994](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01459754))
$$M(z)=C(zM(z)).$$

Comment: Absolutely (+1). It should be noted that, although clearly $m_0=E(1)=1$, if I'm not mistaken using that definition one should define $\kappa_0 =1$ (differently from classical cumulants where one has $c_0=0$).